# Create object with methods

Tags: ruby

I would like to create an object with one simple get method:
I would like to use a valid code that looks somehow like that:

```
   obj = Object.new {def people() return @people_arr end}
```

**Whats the shortest code you know to do that? Thanks**

Comment: Where would `@people_arr` be defined? What is your goal?

Comment: I need it because of testing purposes, like that I can easily change the variable

Comment: You won't be able to change the value of `@people_arr` from the outside of that object.  If you explain a little bit further what you are trying to accomplish, I am happy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a singleton method on that object like:

```
obj = Object.new
obj.define_singleton_method(:your_method) { puts 'this is my awesome method only defined for this object' }
```

Comment: Why not `def obj.your_method; puts 'foo'; end`?

Comment: That works too.  I prefer the singleton style because since you are not within the context of that object (within its definition), it feels more explicit of what you are doing.